# Access denied on phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am not able to login into phpmyadmin. It shows the following error.

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I tried to login to run `mysql -u root -p`,
but it also shows the same error.

Comment: Dumb question, but you're sure you entered the correct password, right?

Comment: I had the same issue. May be you should check this answer: http://superuser.com/a/1071043/592085

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below.

1. Start the MySQL server instance or daemon with the `--skip-grant-tables` option (security setting).

   ```
   $ mysqld --skip-grant-tables
   ```
2. Execute these statements on new terminal.

   ```
   $ mysql -u root mysql
   $mysql> UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('my_password') where USER='root';
   $mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```

If you face the unknown field Password error above use:

```
update user set authentication_string=password('my_password') where user='root';
```

3. Finally, restart the instance/daemon without the `--skip-grant-tables` option.

   ```
   $ /etc/init.d/mysql restart
   ```

You should now be able to connect with your new password.

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

Enter password: `my_password`

Comment: mysql -u root is also showing the same error.

Comment: @AjayPandita : I have updated my answer, please follow the procedure and check.

Comment: Your answer might not work in some cases. Different MySQL versions and setups use a different field other than `password`. @AjayPandita if you're still having trouble, follow the directions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Also, by not specifying the host as `localhost`, your answer possibly overwrites _all_ root login's passwords. In _this user's case_ that's probably OK. But not for other users with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL authentication is a 'many splendored thing', or FUBAR depending on how you look at it. Different versions and setups can use different authentication methods. Arzyfex's advice might not work all the time. The best advice is to follow the MySQL manual here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html. To handle the various different authentication formats, `mysql` wants you to use `set password for root`, but this command will not work when `--skip-grant-tables` option is used at server startup! So the prescribed formula is to start the mysql server with a special init-file which contains the `set password` command.